# Parsley validation starts immediately when form loads and shows errors

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, validation, parsley.js

Parsley validation starts immediately when form loads and shows errors.
How can I prevent this at start?

This is my code:

**UPDATE**: HTML added
I'm adding validation by adding data-parsley-validate="" to form tag. Is this needed When I'm using parsley() function? Which way is better?

```js
// Activate validation
$("#form_register").parsley();

// On validation
$('#form_register').parsley().whenValidate().done(function() {
    $("#form_register").submit();
});

// Validate when submit button clicked
$('#form_register .btn-submit').click(function(){
    $('#form_register').parsley().validate();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://rawgit.com/guillaumepotier/Parsley.js/2.8.1/dist/parsley.js"></script>
<form id="form_register" method="post" data-parsley-validate="">
<label for="username">usename :</label>
<input type="text" name="username" id="username" class="form-control" autocomplete="username" requireddata-parsley-remote="register/ajax_username_exists/{value}" data-parsley-remote-reverse="true">
<label for="password">Password :</label>
<input type="password" name="password" id="password" class="form-control" autocomplete="new-password" required pattern="(?=^.{8,}$)((?=.*\d)|(?=.*\W+))(?![.\n])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[a-z]).*$" >
<label for="repassword">Password again:</label>
<input type="password" name="repassword" id="repassword" class="form-control" required autocomplete="new-password" data-parsley-equalto="#password" >
<label for="first_name">First Name :</label>
<input type="text" name="first_name" id="first_name" class="form-control" autocomplete="name">
<label for="last_name">Last Name:</label>
<input type="text" name="last_name" id="last_name" class="form-control" autocomplete="family-name">
<label for="mobile_number">Mobile :</label>
<input type="text" name="mobile_number" id="mobile_number" class="form-control" autocomplete="mobile" pattern="^09\d{9}$" >
<label for="phone_number">Phone :</label>
<input type="text" name="phone_number" id="phone_number" class="form-control" autocomplete="tel" pattern="^\d{8,12}$" >
<label for="address">Address :</label>
<input type="text" name="address" id="address" class="form-control" autocomplete="street-address">
<label for="date_birth">Birth Date:</label>
<input type="text" name="date_birth" id="date_birth" class="form-control" autocomplete="bday" placeholder="0000-00-00" pattern="^\d{4}-\d{1,2}-\d{1,2}$"  value="1975-01-01">
<input type="button" value="Register" class="btn btn-primary btn-submit">
</form>
```

Comment: Can you post the form?

Comment: I added the form

Comment: let me check the form and will post an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need a basic validation as shown in your example, you don't need to worry about the `events` like `field:validated`. You can simply call the `validate()` function and that would validate your form before submission.

You have to change the submit button as below so it would submit the form when the validation is successful. 
(Change the type to `"submit"`, not `"button"`)

```
<input type="submit" value="Register" class="btn btn-primary btn-submit" />
```

Then remove all your Javascript code and keep only the following.

```
$('#form_register .btn-submit').click(function(){
    $('#form_register').parsley().validate();
});
```

This will perform a validation when you submit the form and when it's success, it will submit the form.

Here is a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/nimeshka/nx4aLthp/38/

hope it helps :)

Comment: This works perfectly when I'm not using ajax. If I add a $('form').submit() the form will be submitted even if validation failed!

Comment: @rostamiani feel free to ask if you need any help.

Comment: Thanks. This was a new question and asked it here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51345227/submit-is-always-executed-even-when-parsley-validation-fails/51345310