# .submit() is always executed even when Parsley validation fails

Tags: jquery, validation, form-submit, parsley.js

I'm using parsley.js for validation. It does the job without using Ajax.
But when I add a .submit() function, its always fired and does not wait for validation.

**UPDATE: I need to use remote validation too**

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  $('#form_register').submit(function(){
    alert('The form submitted');
  })

});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/rostamiani/mzdvLpnt/3/

It works in fiddler but not in my page. The I attached my page:
https://ufile.io/hm7w5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPDATE**
**This code does not work for remote validation.
When remote validation is used, isValid returns null!**

I used isValid() function to check validation status at submit.

```
$('#form_register').submit(function(e){

    // Prevent normal submittion
    e.preventDefault();

    // If the form is not submitted yet, skip
    if (! $('#form_register').parsley().isValid()) {
        return;
    }

    alert('The form submitted');
}
```